# Working with dates & times - nonatomic expression expected

Tags: date-and-time

Please note that I am new to Mathematica.

I am endeavouring to import data from a CSV file with the first column a date and time. The import appears to work fine and returns the results I expect:

```
In:= date = data[[3 ;; Length[data], 1]]

Out= {"2015-10-28 18:01:55", "2015-10-28 18:02:17", "2015-10-28 18:02:32", …
```

The data values also import correctly.

Attempting to convert the "date" to a `DateList` list using `DateList` returns an error:

```
In:= dateLst = MapAt[DateList, #, 1] & /@ date

Out= First::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in First[2015-10-28 18:02:17]. >>
DateList::arg: Argument First[2015-10-28 18:01:55] cannot be interpreted as a date or time input. >>
Last::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Last[2015-10-28 18:01:55]. >>
```

Attempting to solve this I added:

```
Block[{$DateStringFormat = {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day", " ", 
    "Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second"}}, DateString[]]
"2015-11-01 10:58:57"
```

but it made no difference.

Clearly I am missing something fundamental with how to work with dates and times but have been unable to find a tutorial that addresses this.

Please give me some pointers.

Comment: I think you are over complicating: `dt = {"2015-10-28 18:01:55", "2015-10-28 18:02:17", 
  "2015-10-28 18:02:32"}` then `DateList /@ dt` seems to handle this without problem. It will be more complicated with more complex nested structures. MapAt` seems unnecessary as described.

Comment: It is actually the MapAt that is causing the problem. It works at lists, but your combination with Map causes its argument to be a single item, not a list. The error message tries to convey this, but this might not be that clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
dates = DateList /@ {"2015-10-28 18:01:55", "2015-10-28 18:02:17", "2015-10-28 18:02:32"}
```

> {{2015, 10, 28, 18, 1, 55.}, {2015, 10, 28, 18, 2, 17.}, {2015, 10, 28, 18, 2, 32.}}

To get the dates:

```
dates[[All, ;; 3]]
```

> {{2015, 10, 28}, {2015, 10, 28}, {2015, 10, 28}}

To get the time stamps:

```
dates[[All, -3 ;;]]
```

> {{18, 1, 55.}, {18, 2, 17.}, {18, 2, 32.}}